# R: ddply() guidance needed

Tags: r, plyr

```
df=
ID  Order_nr    C             D
1   1     N87.0     N87.0
2   1     N87.1         N87.1
3   1     N87.1         N87.1   
4   1     N87.1     N87.1
4   2     N87.0     N87.1
5   1     D06       D06
6   1     N87.0     N87.0
7   1     N87.1     N87.1
7   2     N87.1     N87.1
7   3     N87.0     N87.1
7   4     N87.0     N87.1
7   5     N87.0     N87.1
7   6     N87.0     N87.1
8   1     N87.0     N87.0
```

For better Pic :

[image]

I have to create the column D, which is uniqly set for every ID using the Order_nr and C. 
I have do something like this `df$D = df$C[Order_nr == 1]`
ID 1 only appeares once so there isn't much to choose from, but ID 7 appeares 6 times and I need to add N87.1 to all of those 6 lines since  `df$C[Order_nr == 1] => N87.1`

I have tried to do this in numerous ways and failed. So far I have managed to do something close to it using double for loops, but that wasn't perfect or needed anyways.

Example of what I'm set with right now:

```
foo <- function(df) {
  C = df$C[df$Order_nr == 1] }
ddply( df, .(ID),mutate, foo)
```

That doesn't seem to do anything though. Could someone point me in the right direction.

On side note. Is there a specific way to refer the the different subsets that ddply creates and later puts together into 1 data.frame.
Lets say that there are 10 different ID's and there is 5 to 10 of each ID. If i used ddply(df,.(ID),...), then how do I refer the the subset that has only ID = 1, 2, ...

**EDIT**
Metrics code did the magic by applying the head() function

```
ddply(df1,.(ID),transform,E=head(C,1))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make it easy for other people to reproduce your data, either paste the output from `dput(df)` or provide code to create a toy example (as I've done in my answer).

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: You've got two good answers below, but I just wanted to point out that your `foo` function isn't working because it returns a vector instead of a `data.frame`. Whatever function you pass to `ddply` has to return a `data.frame`, or it'll just give you what you started with. aosmith's answer works because he used `mutate`, which *modifies* the `data.frame` you pass to it.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of using `ddply` to assign a value for each row with `mutate`, this is how I would have approached it.  I name the new column `D2` so I could compare it to your column `D`.

```
ddply(df, .(ID), mutate, D2 = C[Order_nr == 1])
```

I think some of the trouble you were having has to do with your function `foo`.  That function expects you to give it a data.frame, but when you use `ddply` with `mutate` you will be working with columns within the data.frame.  I'm still looking a `ddply` option to that uses your original function, but I'm not sure if it will work out.

**Edit**

To follow up on your function `foo`, the first problem you had is it didn't return anything.  I always have to check my functions on a simple example to make sure they are doing what I want them to do. Notice

```
foo(df[df$ID == 7,])
```

doesn't return an answer, which is a red flag that something is wrong.

I ended up changing you function to

```
foo = function(df) {
  C = as.character(df$C[df$Order_nr == 1])
  C
}
```

You could use this with `ddply` without `mutate`, which expects a function for the entire data.frame.  However, you'd have to combine this result with the `merge` answer from @RichieCotton.  I'd stick to using the column names as in my example above.

```
ddply(df, .(ID), foo)
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, but it seems that Metrics managed to give me the desired result using the head() function.

Comment: @KarlRäis If my original answer didn't give you the desired result you should let me know because it works for me.  The edit was just an extra teaching moment to help you understand R and `ddply`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `ddply`, you need `merge`.

A reproducible dataset:

```
n_groups <- 8
n_reps <- sample(6, n_groups, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(
  ID       = rep(seq_len(n_groups), n_reps),
  Order_nr = unlist(lapply(n_reps, seq_len)),
  C        = sample(letters, sum(n_reps), replace = TRUE)
)
```

Create a lookup table of the ID and the group.

```
lookup <- subset(df, Order_nr == 1, c(ID, C))
colnames(lookup) <- c("ID", "D")
```

Now merge on the ID column.

```
merge(df, lookup, by = "ID")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there is a slight problem. I MUST do the same thing using plyr library. I'm sure I would have been able to do it without help if I were allowed to use merge, but in this case I have to do it with ddply() and I can't get my head around it since we weren't given much material on it and I weren't able to find anything useful on the web also. I'm just out of ideas.

Comment: If this is homework, make sure you cite the help that you've been given here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that Order_no is already sorted before applying `ddply` and there is Order_nr 1 for all

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df1,.(ID),transform,E=head(C,1))
   ID Order_nr     C     D     E
1   1        1 N87.0 N87.0 N87.0
2   2        1 N87.1 N87.1 N87.1
3   3        1 N87.1 N87.1 N87.1
4   4        1 N87.1 N87.1 N87.1
5   4        2 N87.0 N87.1 N87.1
6   5        1   D06   D06   D06
7   6        1 N87.0 N87.0 N87.0
8   7        1 N87.1 N87.1 N87.1
9   7        2 N87.1 N87.1 N87.1
10  7        3 N87.0 N87.1 N87.1
11  7        4 N87.0 N87.1 N87.1
12  7        5 N87.0 N87.1 N87.1
13  7        6 N87.0 N87.1 N87.1
14  8        1 N87.0 N87.0 N87.0
```

Comment: Thank you. I was expecting this to be a very short code,but this just left me speechless. I will remember these head/tail functions forever.